# How can I catch exceptions generated in PreApplicationStartMethod?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I have an ASP MVC application that is hosted in a medium trust environment.  This means that the only code that can execute is what is defined in the code permissions of the applications trust file.  I am seeing that in the newer MVC applications a method `ExecutePreAppStart()` is called.  This method then tries to execute `LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()`.  When this occurs a permissions error is generated

> [PolicyException: Execution permission cannot be acquired.]

If the app has not been granted the explicit permission to execute that assembly.  This is the expected outcome.

The issue here is that prior to PreApplicationStartMethod's implementation this error would bubble up to `Application_Error` in the global.asax.  With PreApplicationStartMethod this is no longer the case.  Since the PreApplicationStartMethod is not in code that I control, how can I trap for an error that may occur?

I have tried to create my own PreApplicationStartMethod to catch the exception but, it never reached the break point because the application is never fully loaded.

So, is there a way to catch errors for someone else's PreApplicationStartMethod?  My end goal is to just be able to publish the exception.

**Attempt at catching error:**

```
[assembly: System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(mynamespace.Initializer), "Initialize")]

namespace mynamespace
{
    public static class Initializer
    {
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            //Do something here to catch errors/bind event? but I never get this far at runtime
        }
    } 
}
```

**Stack Trace:**

> System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +772
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.**LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory**()
>   +259    System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo
>   ai) +163
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +230
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies()
>   +76    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +343
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.**ExecutePreAppStart**() +176
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +734

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why you need to run your application in a medium trust environment. The preapplicationstart method always worked for me and was able to catch exceptions when an error occurred. Usually, i would run an infinite while loop and execute operations every x amount of minutes. The only difference between your code and mine is that i usually define the Initializer class as public class without being static, i only set the initialize method as static.

This works for me even in azure web apps environment. So, make ways to elevate the trust level of your environment, but before test this on your development machine and make sure it works so you are sure that the error is thrown from server security policy.